# Use of None in Array indexing in Python

Tags: python, theano

I am using the LSTM tutorial for Theano (http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html). In the lstm.py (http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/lstm.py) file, I don't understand the following line:

```
c = m_[:, None] * c + (1. - m_)[:, None] * c_
```

What does `m_[:, None]` mean? In this case `m_` is the theano vector while `c` is a matrix.

Comment: I haven't worked with Theano, but it seems it has tight integration with NumPy, which introduces the syntax you are dealing with: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: Ondrej Slinták is correct.  Looking over code in https://github.com/Theano/Theano, Theano tensors are implemented as NumPy arrays and lstm.py shows that slice() returns a 2 or 3 dimensional NumPy array. With NumPy.array slicing, None is the same as the newaxis object which adds an axis (dimension) to an array so m_[:, None] wraps each element of m_ in an array, e.g.  given import numpy as np; a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), then a[:,None] is np.array([[[1, 2]], [[3, 4]]])

Comment: Make sure to do a basic numpy tutorial followed by the Theano tutorial. That will answer a lot of questions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered on the Theano mailing list, but is actually about the basics of numpy indexing.

Here are the question and answer
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/jq92vNtkYUI

For completeness, here is another explanation: slicing with `None` adds an axis to your array, see the relevant numpy documentation, because it behaves the same in both numpy and Theano:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis

Note that `np.newaxis is None`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6)

print a.shape  # yields (5, 6)
print a[np.newaxis, :, :].shape  # yields (1, 5, 6)
print a[:, np.newaxis, :].shape  # yields (5, 1, 6)
print a[:, :, np.newaxis].shape  # yields (5, 6, 1)
```

Typically this is used to adjust shapes to be able to broadcast to higher dimensions. E.g. tiling 7 times in the middle axis can be achieved as

```
b = a[:, np.newaxis] * np.ones((1, 7, 1))

print b.shape  # yields (5, 7, 6), 7 copies of a along the second axis
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the Theano vector's `__getitem__` method expects a tuple as an argument! like this:

```
class Vect (object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=list(data)

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.data[key[0]:key[1]+1]

a=Vect('hello')
print a[0,2]
```

Here `print a[0,2]` when `a` is an ordinary list will raise an exception:

```
>>> a=list('hello')
>>> a[0,2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

But here the `__getitem__` method is different and it accepts a tuple as an argument.

You can pass the `:` sign to `__getitem__` like this as `:` means *slice*:

```
class Vect (object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=list(data)

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.data[0:key[1]+1]+list(key[0].indices(key[1]))

a=Vect('hello')
print a[:,2]
```

Speaking about `None`, it can be used when indexing in plain Python as well:

```
>>> 'hello'[None:None]
'hello'
```

Comment: Indeed, calling `a[:, 3]` on an ordinary list gives `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`. However, I don't really see what the tuple here is. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: the tuple is the comma :P Yeah, the actual thing in python that makes a tuple a tuple is a comma, not the parens. You could possibly write it a[ (:, 3) ] if you wanted to be more clear.

Comment: @RishavKundu that's the reason why `("boo!")` is not a tuple, and `"merp",` is.