# Comparing two numpy arrays with different lengths line-wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, comparison

I am trying to compare all to all elements of two different lenght arrays. Lets say I have an array:

```
A = np.array([[15,25,22],[200,200,20]])
```

And second array is an array I want to compare with:

```
B = np.array([[150., 350.],
 [250., 450.],
 [150., 350.],
 [400., 600.],
 [400., 600.],
 [650., 850.],
 [550., 750.],
 [650., 850.]])
```

What I need is to compare all the elements on index 0 of all arrays in A (`A[:, 0]`) with all elements on index 0 in all arrays in array B (`B[:, 0]`).

If A is just a simple array such as `A=[25,40,25]`, then it is simply done as:

```
smaller = np.array(A[0] > B[:, 0]).astype('int')
```

I thought I can transform it to 2d comparison such that

```
smaller = np.array(A[:, 0] > B[:, 0]).astype('int')
```

This is not working, error is clear, `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (8,)`. I understand that this way I cannot compare it but I was not able to find the way how to do so.

My desired output would look like this:

```
[[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
 [True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

Comment: Try to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55985900/custom-matrix-multiplication-with-numpy maybe it can help (maybe just replacing multiplication by `>` could work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MichaelSzczesny I got the solution I was looking for. Simply adding `[:, None]` to the comparison worked:

```
smaller = np.array(A[:, 0][:, None] > B[:, 0]).astype('int')
```

As explained in [Use of None in Array indexing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492699/use-of-none-in-array-indexing-in-python), it adds an axis to the array. Thus from

```
[ 15 200]
```

We get

```
[[ 15]
 [200]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can have

```
np.array([A[i,0] > B[:, 0] for i in range(A.shape[0])])
```

Comment: I was thinking about it but I would like to avoid looping if possible for efficiency, the real arrays are way longer than those provided as examples.